# How to change style of combo box in Vaadin 10

Tags: css, vaadin, shadow-dom, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I would like to adapt a combo box component's CSS. The combo box has my style class `custom1` added which should disable border radius for left corners.

In my *shared-styles.html*, I tried to adapt CSS properties:

```
.custom1 {
    --lumo-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

This is changing the styles but it is not exactly what I want. According to [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/theme/integrating-component-theme.html), I should follow [this wiki](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki) to apply local scope styles for the web component. So, I tried:

```
<custom-style>
<style>
...
</style>
</custom-style>
<dom-module id="my-combo-box-theme" theme-for="vaadin-combo-box">
  <template>
    <style include="vaadin-combo-box-default-theme">
       :host(.custom1) [part="input-field"] {
          border-top-left-radius: 0px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
       }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

However, it didn't work and the part `input-field` is located like that:

```
<vaadin-combo-box>
    <vaadin-text-field>
        ...
            <div part="input-field">
                ...
            </div>
        ...
    </vaadin-text-field>
</vaadin-combo-box>
```

Which is a problem I guess, because it is a shadow DOM under a shadow DOM? **How can I style that part?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a style/theme module for `vaadin-text-field` which exposes a new custom property for `border-radius`, which you can then adjust from the style/theme module for `vaadin-combo-box`.

Here’s a similar answer on the Vaadin Forum (for `text-align`): https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17197360

Comment: That works, thank you. However, it feels complicated and a little error prone in case Lumo theme is changed because I need to explicitly specify the border radius for the case that it is the "normal" text field: `border-top-left-radius: var(--my-border-radius-override, var(--lumo-border-radius)) !important;`

Comment: Shameless plug: I added this solution as a recipe on https://vaadin.recipes/?p=45

Answer (score 1):

This works (at least in latest Chrome).

```
<dom-module id="my-combo-box-theme" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">

    <template>

        <style>

            /* styling for combo-box */

            :host-context(vaadin-combo-box.custom1) [part="input-field"] {

                border-top-left-radius: 0px;

                border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;

            }

        </style>

    </template>

</dom-module>
```

The key here is to use `:host-context` CSS rule to only target `text-field` part if it's under `vaadin-combo-box`

`:host-context` basically allows to target ShadowDOM-in-ShadowDOM

The more in-depth description of `:host-context` can be found on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()

Comment: Unfortunately `:host-context()` is not polyfilled by ShadyCSS, AFAIK.

Comment: True, I didn't think about that.